# How do I fix OpenAPI error in seemingly correct 'inputSpec' for code generation?

Tags: java, jpa, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm trying to run the OpenAPI generator, but I keep getting an error message that doesn't make sense.

`Failed to execute goal org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT:generate (default-cli) on project miguelmunoz.challenge: The parameters 'inputSpec' for goal org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT:generate are missing or invalid`

The trouble is that my `inputSpec` value points to a valid .yaml file. The file is at `src/main/resources/yaml/pizzeria.yaml` and I've used copy and paste to ensure there are no spelling errors in that path. You can download a minimum reproducible test case at https://github.com/SwingGuy1024/OpenAPI_inputSpec_Bug.

Here's my plugin spec:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- RELEASE_VERSION -->
            <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <!-- /RELEASE_VERSION -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- General Configuration properties taken from -->
                        <!-- https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/README.md -->
                        <!--Changed to https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin-->
                        <!-- Modifications from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64304049/how-to-create-a-spring-boot-rest-server-using-openapitools/64363872#64363872 -->
                        <ignoreFileOverride>${project.basedir}/my-springboot.ignores</ignoreFileOverride>  <!--Added-->
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/yaml/pizzeria.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <!--the language tag was replaced by the generatorName tag:-->
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <!--<templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/gen/templates/</templateDirectory>-->
                        <!--<templateResourcePath>${project.basedir}/src/gen/templates/</templateResourcePath>-->
                        <!-- <output>${project.basedir}</output>-->
                        <!-- Defaults to ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/openapi -->
                        <apiPackage>com.dummy.pizzeria.api</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>com.dummy.pizzeria.model</modelPackage>
                        <invokerPackage>com.dummy.pizzeria</invokerPackage>
                        <packageName>com.dummy.pizzeria.objects</packageName>
                        <groupId>neptunedreams</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pizzeria</artifactId>
                        <library>spring-boot</library>
                        <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                        <!--<output>${project.basedir}/my-springboot</output> &lt;!&ndash; Added &ndash;&gt;-->
                        <!--<generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>-->
                        <configOptions>
                            <!-- configOptions are specific to the spring generator. These are taken from -->
                            <!-- https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/spring.md -->
                            <sourceFolder>gen</sourceFolder>
                            <bigDecimalAsString>true</bigDecimalAsString>
                            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary> <!-- Default-->
                            <delegatePattern>false</delegatePattern>
                            <performBeanValidation>true</performBeanValidation>
                            <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                            <skipDefaultInterface>false</skipDefaultInterface>
                            <library>spring-boot</library>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 19):

Use the **compile** phase of maven

```
mvn clean compile
```

instead of using the plugin directly

```
mvn openapi-generator:generate
```

Explanation :

> The trick is, not to call the plugin directly, but instead call "mvn
> clean compile". It´s a little but confusing about maven, but okay for
> me. Sorry guys.

from here: [OpenAPI Generator | Issue tracker](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/2207)

Comment: "mvn clean generate-sources" is sufficient. by the way is this the ONLY way to pass configuration from pom?! i prefer calling plugin directly due to project can be really huge.

Comment: Same for me but you can't @simon. Try to externalize your API into a small maven module and include it into the main project as a library/dependency. Like that, I can just do the "maven clean compile" only on your tiny library.

Answer (score 1):

- You must rename the rules for OpenApi.

For example:

```
api.yaml
```

- than, you must pass the file into **/resources/**
- So, Your file will be into

**/src/main/resources/api.yaml**

- After, you must change pom.xml into    :

```xml
...
 <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
...
```

- Now, perform a command:

```bash
mvn clean compile
```